# How to make auto execution of sql queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have lots of query with select and update. i want to execute it automatically in Oracle SQL developer. I also want to note the execution time of each query.
Please suggest way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please remove that MySQL tag.

Comment: Have you tried oracle jobs? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse002.htm#i1006395

Comment: @FrancescoSerra Hi actually i don't know how to make job and run job with these queries

Comment: You can create a procedure to sobstitute your queries, then you can schedule them as described in the web page: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse002.htm#i1006395 or similar.

Comment: ok.. thnx @FrancescoSerra